# Toggle image visibility using MVVM in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have 2 images visibility using MVVM in Xamarin forms. 1 image represents nothing selected and the other should turn first image off and turn on second image when a selection is made on the form.

**XAML:**

```
<Image x:Name="greenCheckImage" BackgroundColor="#F5E9E9" Source="GreenCheckmark.gif" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding GreenCheck}"></Image>
<Image x:Name="grayCheckImage" BackgroundColor="#F5E9E9" Source="GrayCheckmark.gif" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding GrayCheck}"></Image>
```

**Model:**

```
public bool GrayCheck { get; set; }
public bool GreenCheck { get; set; }
```

**View Model:**

```
    private bool grayCheck;
    
    public bool GrayCheck
    {
      get
      {
         return grayCheck;
      }
    
      set
      {
         if (grayCheck != value)
         {
            grayCheck = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }
    }

private bool greenCheck;

public bool GreenCheck
{
  get
  {
     return greenCheck;
  }

  set
  {
     if (greenCheck!= value)
     {
        greenCheck= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
     }
  }
}
```

Here is my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged which should be handling the page update right?

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Everything is getting set properly when page loads and clicking on the a selection is also firing correctly and the true/false on IsVisible is also being set properly; however the unslected image still remains on the graycheck rather than what should be being displayed is the greencheck and the graycheck should not be visible anymore.

What am I missing here?
TIA!
Rick...

Comment: you didn't post the code that actually toggles the properties, but I assume that you need to set `GreyCheck = false` whenever you set `GreenCheck = true`

Comment: How do you trigger the Selected and UnSelected statues? We need more details for that.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Yes Jason that is what is happening in my code. Yes Wendy it is on an imagebutton when clicked it fires the code to do the sets Jason pointed out. Again it goes through this code setting the image visibility properly but it doesnt refresh or show on the screen.

Comment: I want to how do you trigger the Selected and UnSelected statues. Do you try to use the `VisualStateManager` or `TapGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 0):

If binding is working properly do not use/maintain two boolean variables for gray and green. If only one will be visible at one time.

Use greenCheckImage Xaml as it is and use `Data Trigger` for grayCheckImage

```
<Image x:Name="grayCheckImage" BackgroundColor="#F5E9E9" Source="GrayCheckmark.gif" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding GreenCheck}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding GreenCheck}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Image>
```

You can also write a `converter` if doing this in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks Shubham. I will look into this approach. As to your comment "You can also write a converter if doing this in multiple places" the answer here is yes. The user scrolls through a carouselview to select 1 of the images. Based on their selection of an image they like better set the appropriate checks visibility. So based on the users selection I need graycheck to turn off and greencheck to turn on next to the image selected.

Comment: By multiple places, I meant multiple pages. If in a list 1 trigger will take care of all the elements inside

Comment: Thanks. This wont compile it gives error: The type 'Image' does not support direct content.  ??? I'm researching this error to find another workaround.

Comment: Have you not used triggers ever? How are you not able to get this working